# How can i make animation?

Tags: animation

http://themeforest.net/item/various-responsive-html5-portfolio-template/full_screen_preview/6368143

Please ,first of all visit the above link and when you click Button     [ Show All,  Category1 ,Category 2 , Category 3,  Category 1 & 3 ] respectively then you can see  animation in same page. So my question, How can i do it ?

Comment: The links in question are under "Portfolio" on that site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the buttons show all, category1, 2 etc... ? But animation on the web is mostly made using either [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/animation_intro.html), [CSS3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) or with some kinda JavaScript library such as [Jquery](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-animation-tutorials/) I think most people tend to go with either CSS3 or Jquery as Flash can be very annoying.

Personally I prefer to use Jquery because it's very easy to use with knowledge of JavaScript.

A quick [Google](http://www.google.com) search on either one of these will bring up some good tutorials.

Comment: Please go to Portfolio then you can show  [ Show All, Category1 ,Category 2 , Category 3, Category 1 & 3 ]

Comment: Thanks got it now. I can see that site uses something called, PrettyPhoto.js can someone confirm this is what's being used to animate?